# Implementing Sign in with twitter using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth

I am trying to implement sign in with twitter with java script. I searched alot but I am not able to find a simple sample code to implement this like how it is available for `facebook`, `google` and `linkedIn`. Can someone please point me to a simple code sample or guide me on how to write my own `OAuth` requests to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Anywhere used to support client side Sign In but it is deprecated now .

Goto through this link for more details :
https://twittercommunity.com/t/how-do-i-implemente-sign-in-with-twitter-from-javascript-now-that-anywhere-will-be-deprecated-soon/1180/2